# How to limit the neural network regression output between 0 and 1 without sigmoid or tanh？

Tags: neural-networks

I need to limit the output value to [0,1], but using tanh or sigmoid activation function after the last layer of convolution or full linkage will result in a return gradient of 0, (falling in the level of the activation function), but also do not need to let the value of the sum of 1 (softmax), is there any good way, thanks. I've used laynorm to limit the output size, but it still doesn't work, very hard to train.

Comment: $\tanh$ is restricted between -1 and 1, so it is not a solution that restricts to between 0 and 1. In every event, by construction, any function $f: \mathbb R \to [0,1]$ must have asymptotes at 0 and 1, so you're asking for an impossibility. Perhaps there is a real question lurking in here, but you'll need to explain what problem you're trying to solve and why you need the results to be restricted between 0 and 1. As it stands, the question appears to be an 
[XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).